# Live update the charts.js graph on a web page using json data received from a remote server

Tags: html, arrays, json, chart.js

I am working on displaying weather info received from a weather station to display as live chart on my web page. I am using charts.js library to render weather data that's fetched from the weather station as JSON data.

In The code, function loadChart() fetched the json data about one field from weather station i.e. 'Humidity' and passes it (as int) to dspChrt(hum) to render the graph.

The main task to do in dspChrt(hum) method that renders the graph to put the data received from laodChrt() in an array that is updated each minute to use it as parameter to display live weather data as a line graph.

As the weather station updates data each minute, I am using    setInterval(loadChart, 60000) method to fetch updated json data each minute.

I am following this tutorial that uses this method I am trying to implement.

[[Chart.js] little update example](https://github.com/alan-mushi/alan-mushi.github.io/blob/master/assets/chartjs_example.js)

But it's not working though.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Weather Update</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script>

        function dspChrt(hum[]) { // to be called by loadChart() to render live chart

            var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
            var N = 10;

            for(i=0; i<N; i++)
                hum.push(0);

            var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'line',
                data: {
                    labels: ['M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S', 'S'],
                    datasets: [{
                        label: 'Humidity',
                        data: hum, // json value received used in method
                        backgroundColor: "rgba(153,255,51,0.4)"
                    }, {
                        label: 'Temprature',
                        data: [2, 29, 5, 5, 2, 3, 10],
                        backgroundColor: "rgba(255,153,0,0.4)"
                    }]
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
    <script>


        var myVar = setInterval(loadChart, 60000);


        function loadChrt() { //fetches json data & calls dspChart() to render graph 
            var wData, hum; 
            var requestURL = 'https://cors.io/?http://api.holfuy.com/live/?s=759&pw=h1u5l4kka&m=JSON&tu=C&su=m/s'; //URL of the JSON data
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest({
                mozSystem: true
            }); // create http request

            request.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
                    wData = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                    hum = wData.humidity;

                    console.log("wData: " + wData);
                    console.log("hum: " + hum);

                    dspChrt(hum);
                }
            }

            request.open('GET', requestURL);
            request.send(); // send the request
            //dspChrt(hum);
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="loadChart();">
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Weather Update</h2>
        <div>
            <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have typo in the for function name `loadChart`.
The variable declarations and function definitions are needed to be added before being used.
Reduced the length of array to 7 instead of 10.

Here is updated code snippet. I've added the temperature as well. ;)

```js
var humArray = [];
var temArray = [];
var N = 7;
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
  humArray.push(0);
  temArray.push(0);
}

function loadChart() { //fetches json data & calls dspChart() to render graph 
  var wData, hum, tem;
  var requestURL = 'https://cors.io/?http://api.holfuy.com/live/?s=759&pw=h1u5l4kka&m=JSON&tu=C&su=m/s'; //URL of the JSON data
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest({
    mozSystem: true
  }); // create http request
  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
      wData = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
      hum = wData.humidity;
      tem = wData.temperature;
      humArray.shift();
      humArray.push(hum);
      temArray.shift();
      temArray.push(tem);
      dspChrt(humArray, temArray);
    }
  }
  request.open('GET', requestURL);
  request.send(); // send the request
  //dspChrt(hum);
}
var myVar = setInterval(loadChart, 60000);

function dspChrt(humArray, temArray) { // to be called by loadChart() to render live chart
  var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: ['M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S', 'S'],
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Humidity',
        data: humArray, // json value received used in method
        backgroundColor: "rgba(153,255,51,0.4)"
      }, {
        label: 'Temprature',
        data: temArray,
        backgroundColor: "rgba(255,153,0,0.4)"
      }]
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

<body onload="loadChart();">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Weather Update</h2>
    <div>
      <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much :) 
In the console, it is showing 'TypeError: l._view is undefined'. I wonder what is the reason for that & what effect it has on graph display. As the graph is shown working.